# PosEx on a String with more than 1024 Chars

Tags: html, string, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a simple function to get a value from a HTML's `​meta property="og:image"`:

```
Function HTML_GetOGImage(HTML:String;Var URL:String):Boolean;
Var
  I,A,B,C:Integer;
Begin
  Result:=False;
  A:=PosEx('og:image',HTML,1);
  If A<>0 Then B:=PosEx('content="',HTML,A+9)Else Exit;
  If B<>0 Then C:=PosEx('"',HTML,B+9)Else Exit;
  For I:=B+9 To C-1 Do URL:=URL+HTML[I];
  Result:=True;
End;
```

It works well, but on some websites where the HTML is a long line of chars without carriage returns and `meta` is at a position higher than 1024, the function returns, nothing is done. (i.e. [here](https://www.leparisien.fr/societe/sante/covid-19-fin-de-la-periode-disolement-de-jean-castex-dont-lepouse-avait-ete-testee-positive-suivez-notre-direct-16-06-2021-BKACFU43MBAATAOLEN7BYHNNIY.php)).

What is the best practise to handle long Strings? Is `PosEx` limited in terms of a String's length?

Comment: If that's true, I'd say it is a bug. Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Change your first `PosEx()` to `Pos()`: is the problem still the same? Also "_the function return blank_" is both ambiguous and impossible: which function? What means "blank" to you?

Comment: @HeartWare 10.3, work with all pages html and for this one when it returned nothing i just manually download the HTML in a notepad and found that the og:image is at 1024 pos for O and 1025 for the G

Comment: @AmigoJack i mean nothing happens, even the application is not stuck ! and if i try it with another webpage it extract the image normally ... i tried with POS for the first POSEX, same result

Comment: If you're talking about the HTML from the page you're linking, I don't find "og_image" in column 1024, but in column 4086...

Comment: And I find the following URL using your exact code to scan:
'https://www.leparisien.fr/resizer/tHSUGi9wTnVSkXz4NUvbjObFPVw=/1200x675/cloudfront-eu-central-1.images.arcpublishing.com/leparisien/7S5TB4X22BCGFMC6ZX7FVJXI4U.jpg'

Comment: Like @HeartWare, I tried your code on your page using your Delphi version. And I get https://www.leparisien.fr/resizer/tHSUGi9wTnVSkXz4NUvbjObFPVw=/1200x675/cloudfront-eu-central-1.images.arcpublishing.com/leparisien/7S5TB4X22BCGFMC6ZX7FVJXI4U.jpg

Comment: (Off-topic hint: Don't do `For I:=B+9 To C-1 Do URL:=URL+HTML[I];`. Use `Copy`. And use a proper HTML parser.)

Comment: @HeartWare i tried several url from this site LeParisien, because they put their HTML in block without carriage return, perhaps it was another page, but basically all og:image will be found above the 1024 limit, anyway still have the bug, but i just learned now how to use TJVHTMLPARSER and it work like a charm, so do i have the close the question or let it perhaps someone find a solution ? Many thanks guys

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand +1 for the parser i just tried TJVHTMLPARSER and its ok, thanks

Comment: There's no problem with >1024. As I said, my test found it at position 4000+. Anyway, if you have found an alternative solution, that's the main thing...

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be `PosEx()`'s fault. One can simply counter test this by forcing a situation which you think is the culprit:

```
var
  s: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Just a long string
  SetLength( s, 2000 );
  for i:= 1 to 2000 do s[i]:= Chr( i mod 10+ $30 );

  // The text to be found is clearly after 1024 characters
  s:= s+ 'og:image';
  i:= PosEx( 'og:image', s, 1 );

  // Should not be 0 but instead 2001
  Writeln( i );
```

If this code works for you and the searched text is found then your error is somewhere else. `PosEx()` (and `Pos()`) should also have no problem with much larger strings, i.e. one million characters. I think your understanding is wrong: you expect your variable `HTML` to have contain what you want, but have you even checked its length or content (thru saving it to a file)?

Answer (score 0):

PosEx() works perfectly without any problem. your question is wrong

Run this in your delphi, I don't see any problem.

Unit1.dfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 231
  ClientWidth = 505
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 505
    Height = 231
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 0
    OnDownloadComplete = WebBrowser1DownloadComplete
    ExplicitLeft = 120
    ExplicitTop = 73
    ExplicitWidth = 300
    ExplicitHeight = 150
    ControlData = {
      4C00000031340000E01700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000004C000000000000000000000001000000E0D057007335CF11AE690800
      2B2E126208000000000000004C0000000114020000000000C000000000000046
      8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000}
  end
end
```

unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

const
  siteURL = 'https://www.leparisien.fr/societe/sante/covid-19-fin-de-la-periode-disolement-de-jean-castex-dont-lepouse-avait-ete-testee-positive-suivez-notre-direct-16-06-2021-BKACFU43MBAATAOLEN7BYHNNIY.php';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowser1DownloadComplete(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses System.StrUtils, ActiveX;

function HTML_GetOGImage(HTML:String;var URL:String) : Boolean;
bar
  I,A,B,C:Integer;
begin
  Result:=False;
  A := PosEx('og:image',HTML,1);
  If A<>0 Then B:=PosEx('content="',HTML,A+9)Else Exit;
  If B<>0 Then C:=PosEx('"',HTML,B+9)Else Exit;
  URL := Copy(HTML, B+9, C-B-9); //I prefer <- instead of -> For I:=B+9 To C-1 Do URL:=URL+HTML[I];

  ShowMessage('A = ' + IntToStr(A) +#13#10+ 'B = ' + IntToStr(B) +#13#10+ 'C = ' + IntToStr(C)); //remove this line after test
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(siteURL);
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DownloadComplete(Sender: TObject);
var
  LStream: TStringStream;
  Stream : IStream;
  LPersistStreamInit : IPersistStreamInit;
  URL : String;
begin
  if not Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then exit;
  LStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    LPersistStreamInit := WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
    Stream := TStreamAdapter.Create(LStream,soReference);
    LPersistStreamInit.Save(Stream,true);
    HTML_GetOGImage(LStream.DataString, URL);
  finally
    LStream.Free();
  end;
end;

end.
```